# Split cell value into multiple cells

Tags: microsoft-excel

How do I get Excel to split a sequence of delimited values in a cell over multiple cells?

```
 |    A   |   B
1| 1 2  4 |
2|        |
```

Split over `/\s+/`:

```
 |    A   |   B
1| 1      |
2| 2      |
3| 4      |
```

This is in a pivot table, so I want the pivot table's mechanism to take the split in account, and consider it as if the data came this way from the datasource.

Comment: A screenshot would be good for better comprehension.

Comment: What does this mean: "Split over /\s+/"

Comment: @Sux2Lose Split over one or more whitespace characters.

Comment: I know about the "Text to Columns" feature, under the Data tab in Excel 2007, but I wish to split the values to rows, not columns. Not only that, but this feature doesn't work in a pivot table: Excel complains about changing the data.

Comment: I start to think Excel simply can't change data streamed from a datasource into a pivot table, and that the only way to go about this is to manipulate the data at the datasource side. Thoughts?

Comment: I'm not sure I can split the field into multiple rows though at the database query level. Specifically, I'm using PostgreSQL 7.4.24. I know PostgreSQL 8 has the `string_to_table()` function, but version 7.4 doesn't have this function. Any way, I think this diverts to a whole new question now.

Comment: I don't think there is a native feature of Excel to do this. You either have to play with the data source (Using text-to-columns and then paste special>values>transpose) or use VBA.

Answer (score 0):

As user Sux2Lose has mentioned, there is not necessarily a native method of transposing this data in Excel. There is, however, a way to utilize a word processor for this task. (MS Word, TextWrangler, Notepad++, etc)

I assume that the data is currently in the same row across multiple columns, and you are trying to take that same data and format it in Excel across multiple rows. If you copy this set of data into your word processor, the table is lost, but the tab spacing remain. At that point, you can do a find and replace to change the tab spacing into new line spacing

Find: ^t in word, \t in other word processors
Replace: ^p in word, \r or \n in other word processors

Once you do this, you will be able to paste your data back into Excel in the appropriate format.